# storing a string and int in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello i am trying to understand 2d arrays in java. Basically i am trying to take cellular data from each country and display it like this:

Country   1983   1984    1985
USA        10      20      40
Mexico      2       3       1

Basically taking a string representing country and int representing actual stat number. i take the stats from 1983 to 1985.

My assumption not sure if i am right:
 Create an object of 2d array. 1 for string, 2nd for int. but get lost on the implementation and don't know if this is the right way to go or if anyone could help and make any suggestion will be grateful.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

below is my sample code implementation:

```
public class CellularData
 {
   private String []country;
   private double []stats;
   CellularData [][]array;
   private int year;

  public CellularData(int rows, int column, int year){
  this.country = new String[rows];
  this.stats = new double[column];
  array = new CellularData[country.length][stats.length];
  this.year = year;
   }
  public void insert(String country, double []num){
   //this is where I'm having the problem.
  //don't think  i am right.
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
             array[i] = country;
          for(int j =0;j<array[i].length;j++)
            {
              array[i][j] = num[j];
            }
         }
   }




  //Below is my Test class
  public class TestCellularData(){
  public static void main(String []args){
   final double[] canada = {0,0,0.05,0.23,0.37,0.75,1.26};
              final double[] mexico = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01};
              final double[] usa = {0,0,0.14,0.28,0.5,0.83,1.39};
              int startingYear = 1983;
              CellularData datatable;
              int numRows = 3;
              int numColumns = canada.length;
              datatable = new CellularData(numRows, numColumns, startingYear);
              datatable.insert("canada", canadaPartial);
              datatable.insert("mexico", mexicoPartial);
              datatable.insert("usa", usaPartial);

              System.out.println(datatable);
```

Comment: Different data types in a single array are not possible. You should create a class that takes the country name and contains a map with the year as the key and the stat number as the value. This is also much more expandable than an array.

Comment: You can also use a `Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>`.

Comment: @Tom i haven't done mapping yet. This was an exercise on understanding 2d arrays. i know different data types aren't possible in a single array. The requirement was creating an object with a 2d array. one for string representing country and the other representing integer. How do you go about that?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis i haven't done mapping yet. This was an exercise on understanding 2d arrays. i know different data types aren't possible in a single array. The requirement was creating an object with a 2d array. one for string representing country and the other representing integer. How do you go about that?

Comment: guess your `CellularData#insert` method just fills the `array` with the data, not insert. you may want to loop to find an empty slot first then insert the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided source code has some small problems in it. First of all, you'll have to use an array of `Object` to store `String` and `Double` in it. An array of CellularData can't do that.

The second problems was your `insert` method. It wrote data to every row of the array and delete already stored data that way. To fix that you'll have to search for the first empty row first.

See the following code and the comments for more information.

```
public class CellularData {
  private Object[][] array; // <- use Object instead of CellularData

  public CellularData(int rows, int column, int year) {
    array = new Object[rows + 1][column + 1]; // <- +1 for the heading line and the country name column

    // write head line to array
    array[0][0] = "Country";
    for (int i = 1; i <= column; i++) {
      array[0][i] = year++;
    }
  }

  public void insert(String country, double[] num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i][0] == null) { // <- search for an empty row to insert the data there
        insert(country, num, i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  private void insert(String country, double[] num, int row) {
    array[row][0] = country; // <- write the country to the first column
    for (int j = 1; j < array[row].length; j++) { // <- data starts at the second column
      array[row][j] = num[j - 1]; // <- -1 because the num array is one column shorter than 'array' (due to the country name column in 'array')
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final double[] canada = { 0, 0, 0.05, 0.23, 0.37, 0.75, 1.26 };
    final double[] mexico = { 0, 0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01 };
    final double[] usa =    { 0, 0, 0.14, 0.28, 0.5,  0.83, 1.39 };
    int startingYear = 1983;
    CellularData datatable;
    int numRows = 3;
    int numColumns = canada.length;
    datatable = new CellularData(numRows, numColumns, startingYear);
    datatable.insert("canada", canada);
    datatable.insert("mexico", mexico);
    datatable.insert("usa", usa);

    // print array content
    for (Object[] row : datatable.array) {
      for (Object cell : row) {
        System.out.print(cell + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

The test method prints

```
Country 1983    1984    1985    1986    1987    1988    1989    
canada  0.0     0.0     0.05    0.23    0.37    0.75    1.26    
mexico  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.01    
usa     0.0     0.0     0.14    0.28    0.5     0.83    1.39
```

Comment: why array of objects and not cellularData? from researching on  Objects it seems it's a super class. You can correct if me im wrong and thanks for the input as well

Comment: @user3497437 That is why you can store everything in an array of `Object`, because it is the parent class of every other class. `CellularData` on the other hand has nothing to do with either `String` or `Double`. So the JVM can't know how to cast/convert `String` into `CellularData` or `Double` into `CellularData`.

Comment: so using Object we do not have to worry about casting. Thanks a lot as well for the explanation

Comment: @user3497437 You don't have to worry about casting from `something` to `Object`. But if you want to cast from `Object` to `something` you have to worry about that. Also your IDE should print a waring about an `unchecked cast`. That is why it is recommended to avoid storing data into `Object` and use generics instead. If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it :).

Answer (score 0):

You could instead create an object that encapsulates these data points, and store that in a one-dimensional array instead.  You could even make them sortable by the year by implementing `Comparable`.

```
public class CountryData implements Comparable<CountryData> {
    private final Integer year;
    private final String country;
    private final Integer dataPoint;

    public CountryData(Integer year, String country, Integer dataPoint) {
        this.year = year;
        this.country = country;
        this.dataPoint = dataPoint;
    }

    // presume getters defined

    public int compareTo(CountryData other) {
        return year.compareTo(other.getYear());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're feeling particularly adventurous, you could experiment with Guava's [Table](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) as well.

```
Table<Integer, String, Integer> countryData = HashBasedTable.create();
countryData.put(1983, "USA", 10);
// and so forth
```

Comment: i haven't done Comparable yet. This was an exercise on understanding 2d arrays. i know different data types aren't possible in a single array. The requirement was creating an object with a 2d array. one for string representing country and the other representing integer. How do you go about that?

Comment: You pretty much said it yourself:  you'd use `Object` for you two-dimensional array, and you'd have to put a `String` and an `Integer` inside of the array at specific spots.

Comment: ok i just added my code could you take a look and let me know what i did wrong. Please would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use an array of Object class like**

`Object[][] ob = {{"One", 1},{"Two", 2}, {"Three", 3}};`

**Note:** to access the values you will need to cast the values to the required type (string does not need to be cast explicitly)

**OR**

you should use HashMap Like

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

use its `put(String, Integer)` method to insert the values and `get(index)` to access the values

**Note:** You cannot store the primative types in a `HashMap` but you will have to use `Integer` instead of int and later you can change it to int.

Comment: I am required to use 2 objects and not hashing. Professor has not taught hashing and please bare with I'm new to programming. so for my insert function as above it reads the string and an array of doubles. How do i implement that? Thanks for your reply